# Custom adapter not loading drawableEnd in textview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have custom adapter which display string and icon in textview but on the end of this textview i have drawableEnd in xml which is same to all rows, if the list is bigger then the screen can load the arrow on the end is not drawing, when i scroll down, and if i go up in list, adapter load only icon and text. If i don`t set drawable in adapter the texview is drawing ok, but i want to change my icons pragmatically. I can see in [android dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) will be support in api level 17 but now i cant use it in my adapter, is there a way to solve this?

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="4dp"
android:drawablePadding="4dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/file"
PROBLEM -> android:drawableEnd="@drawable/next" >
</TextView>
```

and my adapter code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context; 
int layout_resourceId;
ArrayList<String> list_text;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout_resourceId, ArrayList<String> list_text) {
    super(context, layout_resourceId, list_text);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout_resourceId = layout_resourceId;
    this.list_text = list_text;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convert_view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convert_view;
    MyItemHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layout_resourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new MyItemHolder();
        holder.text_view = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item);
        holder.icon_view = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (MyItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    //text
    String string_item = list_text.get(position);
    holder.text_view.setText(string_item);

    //icon
    MyExtension.myExtension(string_item);
    int drawable = MyExtension.file_icon_is;
    holder.icon_view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, 0, 0, 0);

    return row;
}
public static class MyItemHolder {
    TextView icon_view;
    TextView text_view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new api lv 17 have working method for this. Separating TextView to TextView and ImageView do the trick for me on old apis

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in every circumstance, but try using `android:width="wrap_content"` with `drawableLeft` and `drawableRight`.

```
MyExtension.myExtension(string_item);
holder.text_view.setDrawableRight(MyExtension.file_icon_is);
```

Comment: i will play whit this but i think there is no way the image to draw on end of row. It will be draw on end of text, right?

Comment: If your text is one line then you should see: `@ My Text @`.

Comment: Hey, just on time i have run updater and what to see api lv 17 is downloading now :) so the new method "setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds (int start, int top, int end, int bottom)" will be available now.